# Google Colab : Local Runtime use

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was currently using google-colab and on the getting started pages, we see:

> Local runtime support Colab supports connecting to a Jupyter runtime
>   on your local machine. For more information, see our [documentation](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

So, when I saw the documentation I connected my colab notebook to the local runtime, after the installations,etc by using the connected tab.

And when I access the memory info:

```
!cat /proc/meminfo
```

The output is as follows:

```
    MemTotal:        3924628 kB
MemFree:          245948 kB
MemAvailable:    1473096 kB
Buffers:          168560 kB
Cached:          1280300 kB
SwapCached:        20736 kB
Active:          2135932 kB
Inactive:         991300 kB
Active(anon):    1397156 kB
Inactive(anon):   560124 kB
Active(file):     738776 kB
Inactive(file):   431176 kB
Unevictable:         528 kB
Mlocked:             528 kB
```

Which is the memory info for my pc, so certainly the access from the notebook is to my pc? Then **how is it any different from my local jupyter-notebook? Now, I can't use the high memory environment of 13 Gigs, nor can I have GPU access.**

Would be great if someone can explain!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantages to using Colab with a local backend stem from Drive-based notebook storage: Drive commenting, ACLs, and easy link-based sharing of the finished notebook.

When using Jupyter, sharing notebooks requires sharing files. And, accessing your notebooks from a distinct machine requires installing Jupyter rather than loading a website.

Comment: Instead of drive commenting, we can have commenting on github too, I guess which is better, since there we can create issues and stuff to get work done.

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62103546/625396

Answer (score 1):

The only benefit is to keep your notebooks in Google Drive.

- you can share them easily
- you have automatic history/versioning
- people can comment on your notebooks

You also have headings with collapsible outline, and probably cleaner UI (if you prefer Colab styling).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR - the short answer is that it's not any different

But, here's an analogy that might help better explain what the point of that is:

Let's pretend Google Colab was something like a video gaming streaming service that enabled users with low-end equipment to play high end graphic demanding video games by hosting the game on their systems. It would make sense if say, we don't have a high end gaming PC or a very strong laptop and we wanted to play a new game that just came out with very high system requirements (which ours barely meets if at all) then naturally we may want to use this streaming service, let's call it Stadia for fun, to play that new game because it lets us play it at 30FPS on 720p resolution for example, whereas maybe using our own computer might give us barely 15 fps at 480p. They would be the people who represent people Like you and I, who want to benefit from the game being run on another system which in this case, would be equivalent to how we want Google Colab to run our iterations on their system. So for us, it wouldn't make sense to have Stadia run locally and use our system resources because there's no benefit in that, even if our saved games were stored locally.

But then there are others, who have high end pc and graphics cards installed, with much better components and resources available to them and let's say they also want to play the same game. Now they could use the same streaming service as us and play at 720p, but since their computer is more powerful and can actually handle let's say the game at 60 FPS on 4k graphics, then they may want to run the game off their own system resources instead of using the streaming service such as Stadia. But that would normally mean, they'd have to get a hardcopy of the game to install it locally on their system and play it that way. And for the sake of the example, let's just pretend it was download only and would require 2 terabytes to install.

So then, if we pretend that stadia had an ability to save them from having download and install the game while still using their systems' resources to provide better graphics while they play, then that would be the case for how or why Colab connecting to a local runtime would serve as a desirable feature for someone. Sharing colab notebooks would be like sharing a game in our theoretical version of stadia, where users wouldn't have to download and install anything so any time there is any update or changes, users would immediately be able to use that new updated version without downloading anything because the actual code (or game install in our metaphor) is run remotely.

Sometimes it's hard to understand things that weren't designed for our use when it contradicts the value which base our decision to use them. Hopefully that helps someone who stumbles across this understand the purpose of it, at least in principle.