# Making Use of Local RunTime on Colab only for accessing data, use remote GPU

Tags: runtime, gpu, jupyter, local, google-colaboratory

I also looked at [Google Colab : Local Runtime use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514243/google-colab-local-runtime-use)

but not found an answer for my needs.

I am interested in making use of local runtime to access my data.
I can also import my local .py files, to make use of functions already created. Good.

Now, thing is, I would like to install GPU based libraries to exploit CUDA and Colab functionalities.

But if install via pip, I see it will execute on my local machine.

Instead I would like to get things executed on a remote machine.

Can I connect via local Runtime to make access to my data, without needing to import them on Google Drive, and use a remote GPU instance to process them ?

Thank you for advising and also for hinting at how the architecture of a "Runtime" may work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this anymore. Google only permits us to use our local machine in the local runtime.