# Access to Jupyter notebook from outside - How to allow google colab to access a local host Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I am trying to connect from google colab to local host - it does not work,
google troubleshooting advise suggests that I should allow local Jupyter notebook to accept colab requests - how to do it ?

Screenshot from local host which confirms that requests from colab are forbidden.
There should be some config modification to allow such requests, is not it ?

[image]

Advise from colab:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### How I fixed my connection issues:

If after the above commands don't work, what finally did it for me was **creating a firewall rule for port 8888**.

Another big one that is in the instructions in your command line but not stated on the provided Google tutorial that some people will miss is that you need to open the URL in your browser that's given to you after launching Jupyter in order for it to create the access cookie and make it valid (sort of speak).

From the screenshot you provided, **make sure you have "http://localhost:8888/?token=2534..." opened in your browser that is logged in with the same account accessing colab** before it will allow access to colab (a separate window or tab will usually pops up on it's own when you run the command though).

Alternatively, you can also add the `--no-browser` tag to prevent the need to open it in your browser

### Other solutions that involve installation issues to mitigate network issues:

There were a number of other troubleshooting steps that were particular to me but dont know if will apply to you but did you have any issues when installing Jupyter?
For me, even though jupyter would still launch, there were errors when installing on Windows, and to fix those I had to replace pip with pipwin and go through the steps that way.

For example

```
pipwin install jupyterlabs
pipwin install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

And in case it helps anyone else coming across this in the future, if you're using the DOS cmd line and have issues launching jupyter, replace the "" with a "^" to indicate continuation

i.e.:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin="https://colab.research.google.com" --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

Comment: for the pipwin examples, I forgot to add "pipwin install pywinpty" as well

Comment: the example for replacing the backslash with a caret does not appear because of formatting, but to clarify it should be replace \ (backslash) with ^ (caret)